# Missing toolbar in TeXnic Center

Tags: texniccenter

For some unreproducible reasons, my TeXnic center misses the toolbar for PDF generating / generating abort / show PDF / show errors / show warnings. It is neither shown / addable in top-level aspect nor extra/option menu. How can I restore this toolbar?

Comment: Menu »View« -> submenu »Toolbars« -> enable »LaTeX«.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no one could help me. I've just re-installed TXC - that solved my problem.